# What priviliges and limitations does an Aircraft(General) mechanic have versus an A&P?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, airframe-and-powerplant

The FAA provides practical test standards for Airframe, Powerplant, and General mechanic certificates. Mechanics seem to demonstrate a preference for Airframe & Powerplant, so much that "A&P" is common shorthand for "aircraft mechanic".

That being the case, my questions are:

- What can a mechanic who is only "general"-certified do and not do, compared to an A&P?
- Is there any real-world benefit in holding a general mechanic certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None. It is required to pass your written general to move on to obtain your Aiframe/Powerplant certification via an Oral & Practical exam. There is no general certification.

If you're looking for a way to work without certification, you can work under a 145's certificate without any.

Comment: Interesting! I wonder why they chose to do it that way. Thanks!