# Difference between general, airframe and power plant concentration courses

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Trying to enrol for an aircraft maintenance technician course but the options are three that’s general, airframe and powerplant concentration. With the general being an affordable course to pursue, will it be advisable if I choose that than airframe or powerplant and would it be enough to prepare me for FAA exams ?

Comment: Are you sure it's 3 separate courses and not just two? "Airframe and powerplant" is the FAA certification. General may not require an FAA exam.

Comment: Closely related:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/62311/167

Answer (score 1):

The US Mechanic certification has two components, Airframe and Powerplant. The license is generally known as an "A&P" license because most candidates choose both. There are, however, three exams. The third is the General knowledge exam. You have three choices for licensing:

- Airframe only
- Powerplant only
- Airframe & Powerplant

For all three options, you must take the General exam as well. Taking a general course will only prepare you for that exam, which does not lead to any license or certification.